# How to change the order of an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, random, char

I am try to change the order of an array of char like this :

```
char arr_char[]="ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ";
```

i used the rand() function in the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;



int main()
{
  char arr_char[]="ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ";
  int arrSize=sizeof(arr_char)-1;

  srand(time(0));

 for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
 {
    cout<<arr_char[rand() % arrSize]<<" ";
 }
}
```

but the rand function repeat some characters more than twice and i want to change the order of the array in which every characters repeat only twice not more .

Comment: First of all, use the facilities in the C++ `<random>` library instead of outdated and bad C functions. What you need is a way to shuffle the array instead of just outputting random elements, which you can do with [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: `rand()` is horrible from a statistical perspective. Use more high resolution random generator provided by C++11. Never use that function.

Comment: Why do you expect the random function not to repeat the values it returns? You are not randomizing an array, you are randomly selecting and displaying a character, and doing that 20 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will probably suffice

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arr_char = "ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ";
    random_shuffle(arr_char.begin(), arr_char.end());
    cout << arr_char;
}
```

Comment: `random_shuffle` has been deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17. `std::shuffle` should probably suffice better.